# Caller Method from parent page from a nested user control

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, nested

I have been looking thru the many posts on calling a method on the parent page from the user control. However my user control is nested inside another user control which is on the parent page. How can i call the method from the parent page from with in this nested control?

Comment: `parent page` sounds like you are missing a platform/tech tag to attract expertise from the right people

Answer (score 0):

All web controls inherit the [WebControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) which has a property called [Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.page(v=vs.110).aspx) that can be used to the get a reference to the control's page.

As such you can simply use:

```
Dim ParentPage as Page = MyUserControl.Page
```

Comment: it diesnt allow me to do ParentPage.Method